# Operações sobre matriz sem tamanho definido

Tags: java, matriz, estrutura-de-dados

Preciso realizar operações sobre uma matriz que ira ser passada por parâmetro, o problema é que seu tamanho não é fixo então não sei como realizar o loop para percorrer até o final de uma coluna ou linha por exemplo.

```
private static void calcularMatriz(int[][] matriz, int linha) {
        int soma = 0;
        // soma os valores em linha
        for (int i = 0; i < ??; i++) {
            System.out.println(matriz[linha][i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vetores são objetos em java, bem como matrizes. Isso significa que existem métodos e atributos que você pode utilizar. Um desses atributos armazena o tamanho do vetor e se chama **length**.

Vamos supor que você tenha a seguinte matriz:

```
int[][] matriz = new int[3][4];
```

Para percorrê-la, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo: (Só como exemplo, está sendo preenchida cada posição da matriz com o valor do i,j correntes).

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++)
        matriz[i][j] = i + j;
```

Para imprimir, portanto, basta fazer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++)
        System.out.println(i + "," + j + "=" + a[i][j]);
```

Assim, para ficar mais claro, veja que para percorrer as linhas utiliza-se:

```
matriz.length
```

Para percorrer as colunas:

```
matriz[i].lenght
```

onde **i** é o índice da linha que se deseja percorrer cada coluna.

### **Nota importante**

Essa maneira de percorrer acima parece desnecessária, já que para toda linha há sempre o mesmo número de colunas. Assim, alguém poderia fazer esse algoritmo da seguinte forma:

```
int linhas = matriz.lenght;
int colunas = matriz[0].length;

for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++)
        matriz[i][j] = i + j;
```

Não há problema em fazer isso se a matriz for sempre retangular. Porém, considere o caso abaixo, retirado de (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4000217/2236741)

```
int[][] matrizIrregular = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4},
};
```

Para esse caso, a maneira de percorrer é a primeira exposta, ou seja, será necessário saber o tamanho pra cada linha percorrida. Assim, na minha opinião, o melhor é fazer de um jeito que atenda qualquer tipo de situação. Portanto, a maneira abaixo é a mais indicada.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrizIrregular.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < matrizIrregular[i].length; j++)
        matriz[i][j] = i + j;
```

Comment: Foi mais rápido, +1.

Comment: Igual no faroeste. :-)